# increase the space between slices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, slice, matlab-figure

I am trying to illustrate 2D matrices in 20 snapshots. I plotted it using `slice` but except the top matrix the rest can not be seen. Is there any way to increase the space between slices in order to be able to see each plane? Can also anyone suggest an alternative way to show the time evolution of a `4x8` matrix for `t=1:20`?
Here is the tiny code I used to plot my data:

```
T2=20;
Xc = zeros(8,4,T2);
for j = 1:T2
    Xc(:,:,j) = mdp2(j).X{1};
end
hs = slice(Xc,[],[],1:T2) ;
lightangle(-45,45);
view([-25 30]);
xticks(linspace(0,20,41));
axis on;
```

How can I change ticks and label for axes here? [image]Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at the DataAspectRatio property of the axes? Stretching the graph in the z axis should do it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for your reply. I have a question: I am trying to plot a `4x8` matrices in 20 slices but using `slice` it seems it shows `3x7` matrices instead. For instance `imagesc` shows values of `4x8` matrices clearly. Is there any way to combine `imagesc` and `slice` for instance?

Comment: `slice` puts the data at the vertices, you have 4x8 vertices, which make 3x7 rectangles. You need to add a row and column to your slice and set the interpolation appropriately to show your data as 4x8 rectangles. There is a Q&A here about that, I’m sure Google will bring it up for you.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have been googling it but couldn't find an answer. How do we add a row and column to the `slice`? Sorry that my question might. seem naive to you but I just recently started coding in matlab and I am pretty new with it. Thanks.

Comment: I can't find the Q&A. You should start with `Xc = zeros(9,5,T2);`, and copy `Xc(1:8,1:4:,j) = mdp2(j).X{1};`. See if that improves your figure.

Comment: By the way, the alternative to show time evolution is to animate the plot: make it into a movie!

Answer (score 4):

Your code with some random data:

```
T2=20;
Xc = zeros(8,4,T2);
for j = 1:T2
    Xc(:,:,j) = rand(8,4);
end
hs = slice(Xc,[],[],1:T2) ;
lightangle(-45,45);
view([-25 30]);
xticks(linspace(0,20,41));
axis on;
```

[image: Original image]

As @CrisLuengo mentioned, here is the `DataAspectRatio` property as is (or use function `daspect()`, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/daspect.html), to get this info):

```
h = gca;
h.DataAspectRatio
ans =

                         1          2.33333333333333          6.66666666666667
% Or use function daspect()
```

From [MATLAB Documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/daspect.html):

> daspect([1 2 3]) specifies that the length of one unit along the
>   x-axis equals the length of two units along the y-axis and three units
>   along the z-axis.

Decreasing `h.DataAspectRatio[3]` increases slice gaps. e.g:

```
set(h, 'DataAspectRatio', [1 2.333 2])
```

Makes the image like this:

[image: Graph with extended Z-axis]

I would also add some transparency to make the data visible:

```
alpha(h, 0.7);
```

[image: Transparent Graph]

> How can I change ticks and label for axes here

Use the axes property or function `XTick`, `YTick`, `ZTick`. Also, change the camera line of sight by `view()` like

```
xticks(1:4);
view(30, 20);
```

which gives:

[image: Changed view]

**EDIT 1**:

When using `slice(Xc,[],[],1:T2)`, it is assumed that `Xc` is a volume data with coordinates defined by the size of `Xc`. These coordinates follow [grid representation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/interpolating-gridded-data.html#bs2o5wb-1) which means the entire grid is defined by these coordinates. If your data represent the coordinates *in between* the grid points (which is the case here), then you should adjust for the missing data at the end of each dimension. So if I construct a binary random dataset with size 8 x 4 x 20 I have:

```
T2=20;
nRows = 8;
nCols = 4;
mdp2 = zeros(nRows, nCols, T2);
for j = 1:T2
    mdp2(:,:,j) = round(rand(nRows,nCols)); % Binary data
end
```

To make the grid size consistent, you should do something like this:

```
Xc = zeros(nRows+1,nCols+1,T2);
for j = 1:T2
    expan1 = [mdp2(:,:,j) mdp2(:,1,j)];
    Xc(:,:,j) = [expan1; expan1(1,:)];
end
```

Which then plots the entire data in `Xc` when doing

```
hs = slice(Xc,[],[],1:T2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have a small question. First, my `8x4` matrices are binary matrices but as you see even in your plot the number of cells are `3x7`?

Comment: You are using `Xc` directly as grid data which means those are data for grid coordinates referring to the grid points (not in between the points). I've added how you can actually plot for the entire 8x4 data in each plane.